# how to refuse socket connection for a Specific IP in Python?

Tags: python, sockets

listenr code :

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = int(raw_input("PORT > "))
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = server.accept()
    buff = 2048
    print addr[0]+" connected."
    c.send("Connection Established")
    data = c.recv(buff)
    if data:
        print data
```

client code:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = int(raw_input("PORT > "))
server.connect((host, port))
buff = 2048
data = server.recv(buff)
if data:
    print data
```

and is it possible to receive data from client and listen on port at the same time ? how?

Comment: after `accept()` run in thread connection with client and at the same time main thread can wait for next client. It is standard method.

Answer (score 0):

After `accept()` use thread to send/receive data to/from client and at the same time main thread can wait for next client running `accept()` again. It is standard method .

Comment: Can you give an example? I haven't used this module.

Comment: see [server.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/socket/basic/version-4/server.py) in folder `version-4` on [GitHub/furas/python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/socket/basic)